# How to ensure that netty pooled memory is not released back to JVM?

Tags: java, netty, heap-memory, pool

Netty pooled buffers allocate 16 MB of heap memory at single point of time (The value is 2 ^ maxOrder, which is set to 11 as default). Buffers are allocated to the application as requested.

Once all the buffers are released to the pool, the 16 MB buffer is open for returning to JVM. If GC kicks in, the memory is reclaimed back.

Is there a way I can ensure that the memory is never released back to JVM?

Comment: This is like provoking a memory leak on purpose. May I ask why would you do that?

Comment: Yeah, it may seem like a memory leak for a general application but for my app, I know for sure that it will be reused.